# SELECT all of a user-defined datatype/structure

Tags: sql, sybase, shortcut, user-defined-types

Is there a shortcut to selecting all the components of a user-defined datatype/structure in SYBASE 10?

So if `Resrv` is a field based on a user-defined datatype/structure, something like:

```
 SELECT Name, Resrv from AGC_AREAPARM
```

(which doesn't work)

Note: `SELECT Name, * from AGC_AREAPARM` doesn't work either.

What does work is specifying each child item, like:

```
 SELECT Name, Resrv.SysReqOper, Resrv.SysReqSpin from AGC_AREAPARM
```

**EDIT :**  If anyone can give me the correct verbiage for the structure, that'd be great.  I'm having a hard time finding it in the Sybase documentation.

Here's a pic of some of the `sp_helptype` output, AGC_RESERVE is the type for the Resrv field:

[image: sphelptype]

Comment: Not familiar with Sybase, but does `SELECT Name, Resrv.* FFROM AGC_AREAPARM` work?

Comment: @Lance: Thanks. Like I said, not familiar with Sybase; that's why it wasn't an answer. It was worth a shot, though. :)

Comment: What you are using isn't user-defined type (as in something created using `sp_addtype`, `Create Domain` or `Create DataType`). It must be something else. Xml perhaps?

Comment: @Thomas, no, it's pre-XML.  It's just like a structure in some programming languages.  It's one parent with multiple children.  When I do a sp_helptype on it, it says the 'kind' is 'structure'.  The children are then listed as 'field's.

Comment: @Lance Roberts - I understand that's how it is behaving. However, the Create Domain/DataType functionality does not allow for multiple attributes. It is merely a mask for an existing system data type. What exact Sybase product are you using? SQL Anywhere?

Comment: @Lance Roberts - Hmm...Now I'm not so sure. The syntax of Create Type/Domain in the docs does not allow for multiple columns. Regardless, you should be able to reference the columns by their full name (e.g. `Col.SysReqSpin, Col.SysReqOper, Col.SysReqMarq`) however I do not believe that "*" will work against a complex type.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: Not very handy with sybase, before I answer, can you post confirm as to does "select * from Resrv" work?

Comment: @mahendraliya, no, `select *` definitely does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what you are seeing is definitely not something created via the `Create Domain` or `Create DataType` predicate. Per the documentation:

> > Domains are aliases for built-in data types, including precision and scale values where applicable. They improve convenience and encourage consistency in the database. *

Instead, my guess is that you are using is a Java class (which sp_helptype shows as a `structure`). There is no mechanism using the Sybase SQL dialect to natively select all properties of a class. You must explicitly declare them in your Select statement:

```
Select Name
    , Resrv.SysRegOper
    , Resrv.SysRegSpin
From Table
```

Comment: While I don't know all the details of how they constructed this database, the programs that use it were all built in C.  I'll probably choose this answer, since I think you're right about there being no mechanism to select all the components.